# UIPinchGestureRecognizer rewrite

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want the pinch recognizer to work from the begining for each event. I mean i want to make the first distance = lastdistance (it is according to the logic of module i am using).
The code is used to increase or reduce the size of an object.
If i write

```
oldDistance = sender->_initialTouchDistance*sender.scale;
```

i get linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPinchGestureRecognizer._initialTouchDistance", referenced from:
  -[DrawArea pinchTouch:] in DrawArea.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

if write

```
- (void) pinchTouch: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ||
        sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
        [docW touchesPinchingScale:sender.scale velosity:sender.velocity withArea:self];
        sender.scale = 1;
    }
}
```

then i am not sure this code works correctly. The scaling of the objectes goes relatively slowly even when my touches are razor fast.
Is that fine?

Comment: You should let us know what's inside touchesPinchingScale:velosity:withArea:

Comment: just resending data data to the dark and mistirous unit. The question is if the code  `sender.scale=1` works correctly.

Comment: That resets the scale of the recognizer. Wether or not that code is ok depends on what you do with the scale inside touchesPinchingScale:velosity:withArea: